# How to concatenate a stored procedure parameter inside a SQL Server string query?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate a parameter of my stored procedure inside a query but it always keeps showing an error . This my query:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT matriculeEmployeur,
                              cleEmployeur,
                              codeDexp,
                              trimestre,
                              annee,
                              page,
                              ligne,
                              matriculeAssure,
                              cleAssure,
                              CONCAT(CONCAT(nom,nomPere,prenom),space(60-LEN(CONCAT(nom,nomPere,prenom)))),
                              carteIdentity,
                              salaire 
                              FROM ##myTempo" queryout "FILEPATH"' +fname+ '-c -T'.
```

The error is shown on the first concatenation symbol [the first plus sign]. What error did I make here?

Comment: Maybe this is because `fname` without an `@` in front is not a valid parameter.

Comment: I added the @ but the errors keeps showing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First construct the command in a `VARCHAR` variable, then use the variable in your exec statement. You can't concatenate strings in place of a stored procedure parameter.

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(8000);
SET @cmd=...; -- build your command shell command here
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```